# Python regex not seen in line reading ADB Logcat

Tags: python, regex, adb

Apologies for the potentially obvious answer.  Using Python 2.7 I am reading an Android ADB logcat stream on the fly line by line.  I am trying to capture the point at which the SIM comes into service on the handset.  I am ok reading other (non regex) strings and successfully capture particular points in the logcat stream, but for some reason my regex is missed.  The last time I used regex on this scale was with Perl, so my interpretation into Python may be a bit skewed.

Here is the string I am trying to capture...

```
< OPERATOR {Orange, Orange, 23430} [ptt1]
```

but equally the string coud be this for another operator...

```
< OPERATOR {O2 - UK, O2 - UK, 23410} [ptt5]
```

My regex attempt is this...

```
\<\sOPERATOR\s\{\w+\,\s\w+\,\s\d+\}\s\[\w+\d\]
```

Is there anywhere obvious I am going wrong?  Am I using "\" in too many places?

Thanks for your time,

MikG

Comment: I should mention that I am using the correct ADB logcat '-b radio' flag for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the fact that you can have characters different from word characters (`\w`) in the operator names.

```
<\sOPERATOR\s\{[^,]+,\s[^,]+,\s\d+\}\s\[\w+\d\]
```

Using negated character classes like `[^,]` *(all that is not a comma)* can solve the problem.

Note that most of the backslashes are useless *(`<` and `,` are not special characters)* (*)

If you are sure of that whitespaces are space characters you can replace all `\s` with a literal space:

```
< OPERATOR \{[^,]+, [^,]+, \d+\} \[\w+\d\]
```

Finally, if your goal is to check the syntax of the line from start to end, you need to add anchors to your pattern:

```
^< OPERATOR {[^,]+, [^,]+, \d+} \[\w+\d]$
```

(If you use `re.match` you can remove the first anchor.)

*(*) you can remove the backslashes before the curly brackets and the closing square brackets too.*

Comment: Thank you very much @Casimir, your example worked.  I'm not good at regex at all, I think I am over cautious in my approach by substituting every character!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<\s*OPERATOR\s*{[^}]*}\s*\[[^\]]*\]
```

Try this.This will get you the string your want irrespective of the operator.You can use `re.findall()`.

You regex `<\sOPERATOR\s\{\w+\,\s\w+\,\s\d+\}\s\[\w+\d\]` does not match `< OPERATOR {O2 - UK, O2 - UK, 23410} [ptt5]` as you have not accounted for `-` or `2` or  before ,.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/44

Comment: Thank you vks for your quick reply, thank you also for the link, very useful, wish I could accept two answers!